# How transaction will work in single INSERT with multiple VALUES in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, insert

I want to ensure inserting 2 rows at one time. If I execute 2 `INSERT` queries concurrently like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_test2]
(
    [column1] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [column2] [int] NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2)
)
-- column1 & column2 = primary key

--query 1
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO Table_test(column1, column2) VALUES (1,1)
    INSERT INTO Table_test(column1, column2) VALUES (2,2)

    COMMIT TRAN

--query 2
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO Table_test(column1, column2) VALUES (2,2)
    INSERT INTO Table_test(column1, column2) VALUES (1,1)

    COMMIT TRAN
```

I think both query1 and query2 will fail. Because table will unlock after first `INSERT` statement, query1 and query2 will success inserting first row. But when each query insert second `INSERT` statement it not work properly.

So I will change query like this. Is it OK?

If first query work properly, second query can be ignored.

```
--query 1
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO Table_test(column1, column2) VALUES (1,1), (2,2)
    COMMIT TRAN

--query 2
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO Table_test(column1, column2) VALUES (2,2), (1,1)
    COMMIT TRAN
```

I wonder if I use single `INSERT` statement with multiple values, is it ensure inserting 2 row at one transaction?

p.s. sorry I am not good at English

Comment: If you are expecting concurrence and competition why not build to anticipate the concurrence?

Your application could/should use some intermediary to handle the concurrence.

You could use a stored procedure that will return a friendly error message if the insert fails.

Or insert into a staging table that doesn't have the key-constraints and have a process that feeds from the staging environment into the core table. 

Or you could let the second insert fail and let the application layer handle the errors

Comment: @theo Thank you for your attention. Yeah I know I can use lock on application level or handle error when problem occur. I just want to know is SQL transaction work as I thought?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

whatever is after `Begin Tran`  will be executed totally or all will fail..So your values clause also will fail..

From Official docs(Emphasis mine)

> BEGIN TRANSACTION represents a point at which the data referenced by a connection is logically and physically consistent. **If errors are encountered, all data modifications made after the BEGIN TRANSACTION can be rolled back to return the data to this known state of consistency**.

so it doesn't matter,if you values clause or seperate DML,everything will fail..

> I wonder if I use single INSERT statement with multiple values, is it ensure inserting 2 row at one transaction?

even if you dont use that entire statements in between those two clauses will be logically under one transaction

moreover values clause is just syntactical sugar,it works as seperate insert statements under the hood,you can see the same from below screenshot

[image]

Comment: I agree transaction can rollback whole things. 
So do you mean whatever I use 'values clause' or 'seperate', transaction will work same?